# how to fix TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Tags: python

I'm calling a Python function defined in another Python file from Flask, where the function sends a string and it will be assigned to a global variable. Then `render_template` sends the global variable to the HTML file to.

But it's giving `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`. How do I fix it?

```
@app.route('/agricul', methods=["post"])
def agricul():
    global summarry
    summarry = check.summary()
    print(summarry)
    return render_template('summary.html', sum=summarry)
```

`check.py` `

```
def summary():
    global summary
    summary='hello world'
    return summary
```

Comment: what is `check`? share your complete code please

Comment: Without the code for check we don't know what the issue is. My best guess is that `check.summary()` is causing the issue because `check.summary` is a string not a function/method.

Comment: check is name of the python file

Answer (score 2):

This function "destroys" itself:

```
def summary(): 
    global summary 
    summary='hello world' 
    return summary
```

When you call `summary()`, the assignment `summary='hello world'` replaces the function with the string `'hello world'`.

In other words, you can call the function only once, and then it’s not a function anymore.

Why you would use a global variable here is unclear, but if you desperately need one you also need to rename either the variable or the function.

A more common implementation would look like

```
def summary(): 
    return 'hello world'
```

Answer (score 0):

you `global summary` has the same name as the function in check.py.  I think python is confused with check.summary, which is a string?